# Is there a way to do multiple shell variable expansions/parameter substitutions?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a line in a script that works in zsh but does not work in bash:

```bsh
SHORTDIR=${${${PWD##*/}//./_dot_}//:/_colon_}
```

This is basically a short/efficient version of `basename $PWD | sed -e 's/\./0/g' -e 's/:/1/g'`.

What's the syntax for stringing together variable expansions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash bad substitution with subshell and substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917439/bash-bad-substitution-with-subshell-and-substring)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, the first part of the substitution has to be a parameter name. An alternative sed version would be:

```
echo $PWD | sed -e 's!.*/!!' -e 'y/.:/01/'
```

Answer (score 1):

I was hoping that there'd be a better way than

```
SHORTDIR=${PWD##*/}
SHORTDIR=${SHORTDIR//./_dot_}
SHORTDIR=${SHORTDIR//:/_colon_}
```

but this is what I'm sticking to.

According to the answers to the question linked by @perreal, bash basically does not allow for expanded variables themselves as a "parameter" and that's why it fails.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw this out there, many people don't know that multiple assignments can be done in one line. E.g.:

```
$ a=1234 a=${a:0:3} a=${a/1}
```

or

```
SHORTDIR=${PWD##*/} SHORTDIR=${SHORTDIR//./_dot_} SHORTDIR=${SHORTDIR//:/_colon_}
```

Comment: Useful to know. Does `a=${a/1}` remove the `1` character? I was under the impression that a trailing slash is needed, per [doc](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html)

Comment: @StevenLu - yes, exactly. The trailing slash isn't needed as the ‘1’ is being replaced with nothing. The doc doesn't mention that; however the bash(1) man page says

    `If string is null, matches of pattern are deleted and the / following pattern may be omitted.`